# Parent bone being rotated by child bone

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I have created a rig that has a ground bone that can move the entire rig. It moves fine when all of the control bones are connected, but as soon as I parent the root bone for the entire rig (the root spine bone), I get some weird issues. If I move the spine bone, it rotates the parent ground bone around the ground bone's head. If I move the ground bone, it wiggles when it is moved. I must be missing something simple, any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Can you upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: There is most likely a dependency cycle issue between some constraint (most likely IK) or a driver and bone parents. The rig has to be inspected to debug where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @MartyFouts Here is the rig:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3888" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3888/)